# How do I count individual names from a column (NOT DISTINCT?) when joining two tables?

Tags: mysql, count, inner-join

I have a table called Orders, which has a primary key of OrderID, an a table called RMA, with a Foreign Key of OrderID to bind the tables together. I have 9 product types. A `SELECT {Product Name} COUNT()` returns the number of orders for each of the 9 products. I am trying to build an output table that has the {Product Name}, {Count of each product in my orders table}, {Count of each product in RMA table after a join}, and a {PercentageReturned} column.

I can get a proper count of orders by product type. Without a join I get the number just in the orders table, and with a join I get a count of orders in the joined table, but I cannot get one table with both results in it. Every attempt returns a table that counts every row, and not the count for each individual product.

```
SELECT SKU, COUNT(*) AS NumberOrdered,
    (SELECT COUNT(SKU)
    FROM Orders
    INNER JOIN RMA
    ON Orders.OrderID = RMA.OrderID
    ) AS NumberReturned
FROM Orders
GROUP BY SKU
ORDER BY NumberOrdered DESC;
```

Result:

| SKU | NumberOrdered | NumberReturned |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BAS-48-1 C | 8385 | 37566 |
| ENT-48-40F | 6186 | 37566 |
| ENT-48-10F | 4329 | 37566 |
| BAS-08-1 C | 4285 | 37566 |
| ENT-24-10F | 4275 | 37566 |
| ADV-24-10C | 4178 | 37566 |
| ADV-48-10F | 4174 | 37566 |
| ENT-24-40F | 2152 | 37566 |
| BAS-24-1 C | 34 | 37566 |

I want the NumberReturned column to provide a count of each SKU that appears once the two tables have been joined, but instead it returns a count of every row in the table. I tried `COUNT(*)`, `COUNT(SKU)` and other things.

I want to also add a PercentageReturned column. I can probably do that by `NumberReturned * 100 / NumberOrdered`, but I have to figure out how to get those values first.

Comment: It's our custom here in the dbms corner of StackOverflow to ask you to [edit] your question to show us a few sample rows of input and a sample, hand-generated, of the output you need from that sample output. And often people find that figuring out the example we need leads them to the answer to their question. So, sample input and sample output, please!

Comment: When isolated your issues will be faqs. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: A [mre] includes: cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK.

Comment: I spent 4 hours trying to find what I was looking for. I don't know how to ask the question, or I wouldn't write all this here. I googled every way I knew how to ask my question, then went through 20 or so solved problems here, read through the categories on two different glossary sites. I spent an hour with a tutor online who didn't get me any further than I got on my own, unfortunately. My last resort was posting here. I would just ask my professor, but it takes 3 days to get an answer back by email. If I could do the things you guys are asking I would just know the answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a LEFT OUTER JOIN (which will keep all the Orders rows, even where there's no RMA row).

```
SELECT
  o.SKU,
  COUNT(*)           AS NumberOrdered,
  COUNT(r.OrderID)   AS NumberReturned
FROM
  Orders          AS o
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  RMA             AS r
    ON r.OrderID = o.OrderID
GROUP BY
  o.SKU
ORDER BY
  NumberOrdered DESC;
```

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted it to do. We learned about the different table joins, but then never had any practical examples except inner joins. I couldn't figure out how to get the count from the joined tables that way. Thank you very much.